# Redirect everything in a subfolder from one domain to another using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website migrated to a new domain. what's the best way to 301 redirect everything from: "domain1.com/folder/" to "domain2.com/folder/" in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
Redirect 301 /folder/ http://domain2.com/folder/
```

This needs to be placed on .htaccess in website root folder of the **`domain1.com`**.